# Automatically add static text to all Exchange calendar entries in a company

Tags: exchange, outlook, calendar

As part of meeting room booking, we would like to make it simple for end-user to order additional services such as food or conference call.

One idea is to add some static text in the body field of all meeting bookings. This text should inform them of the other services and provide an URL link to where they can perform this booking.

Is this possible to achive this with Exchange out-of-the box or third-party products?

Regards
Dagfinn

Update: I believe the current exchange version is 2007

Comment: Thanks for three good suggestions, not easy to select accepted answer. We will most likely implement the auto-accept from the resource mailbox (I don't think we use public folders). Also we will investigate further the possibilities with custom mailtip and custom forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought, can you configure an autoreply for the resource accounts for the rooms that includes your text, or configure a signature so it will get sent when the room auto-accepts the invitation?

It's been a while since I administered Exchange, so I'm not sure if those are the best, or even working, solutions to your problem. Also, you should include what version of Exchange you're running.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which version of Exchange you're running and you don't mention whether the resource is a mailbox or a public folder, but you could look into creating a custom form and publishing it to the Exchange Server Organization forms library.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Exchange 2010 and Outlook 2010, you could try a custom mailtip on the mailbox.

To do that, issue the following in the Exchange Management Shell: `Set-Mailbox Room1 -Mailtip "If you require additional services (such as food) please go to http://intranet.acme-widgets.com"`

Comment: Do you know if mailtips also are applicable for Appointments? All examples I can find only involve new e-mail message